# Find all side-roads of a road via Overpass

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am curious about how roads spread out – in particular how far you can get, if you start at one road and are only allowed to use that road and all its side-roads.

Right now I use [Overpass-Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) with following query to e.g. find "Frankfurter Allee" in Berlin:

```
// gather results
(
  node["name"="Frankfurter Allee"](52.451172, 13.291531,52.587381, 13.518124);
  way["name"="Frankfurter Allee"](52.451172, 13.291531,52.587381, 13.518124);
  relation["name"="Frankfurter Allee"](52.451172, 13.291531,52.587381, 13.518124);
);

// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

So what I'd like to do is query for a road by name (like above), but receive all connected side-roads.

Is something like that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following approach:

```
way["name"="Frankfurter Allee"](52.451172, 13.291531,52.587381, 13.518124);
out geom;
node(w);                 // get all ways' nodes
way[highway](bn);        // find those highway ways, containing previously found nodes
out geom;
```

try it in overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/j09

Comment: That was exactly what I was searching for! Thank you a lot.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. It works for my need to locate nearest connecting street. Although I think the first `out geom;` is unnecessary.